# Returning sum of duplicate elements in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've checked the forum to see if i'll have an answer to this question but so far, i haven't. I have this 2 dimensional array that i want to sum up their values if they are the same. Here is an example.

```
 CAR      CAH     394
 CAR      CAH     96
 CAR      CAP     268
 DOR      CAF     71
 DOR      CAP     96
 DOR      CAP     268
 VAC      GILAB   71
```

After sorting the array, i have the above values. How can i add up all the duplicates in the arraylist. In this case, it will affect CAR|CAH and DOR|CAP. So instead of returning the duplicates, its goint to return one with the combined sum.

Comment: This kind of question doesn't really fit within the purpose of this site. We're here more to help solve specific problems. Usually you have to have written some code first, but it's either causing an error or behaving incorrectly. Please start by attempting a solution yourself, then ask questions about where you are getting hung up.

Comment: `i want to sum up their values if they are the same` if what are the same? Your question isn't exactly clear. You have two strings and a number. Are you summing them if the two strings are the same as another row? Put your source *and* you expected output in the question along with what you've tried.

Comment: Expected value is this:                                                     
      CAR      CAH     490
      CAR      CAP     268
      DOR      CAF     71
      DOR      CAP     364
      VAC      GILAB   71

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* I'm understanding what you are asking correctly (because it really isn't very clear), and given that your array is already sorted, then I you can achieve what you want by using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var source = [
    ["CAR", "CAH", 394],
    ["CAR", "CAH", 96],
    ["CAR", "CAP", 268],
    ["DOR", "CAF", 71],
    ["DOR", "CAP", 96],
    ["DOR", "CAP", 268],
    ["VAC", "GILAB", 71]
];

var last;
var folded = source.reduce(function(prev,curr){
    if (last) {
        if (last[0] === curr[0] && last[1] === curr[1]) {
            last[2] += curr[2];
            return prev;
        }
    }
    last = curr;
    prev.push(curr);
    return prev;
},[]);

alert(JSON.stringify(folded));
```

You are basically building up a new array by comparing the current value to the last value. If the first two elements match, then you add the last one to the previous value and return the array. If they don't match, then you push the new value onto the array.

Comment: yea, that worked for me, i made only one correction which is the '==='. I guess its due to the nature of values in the array. Thanks.